# How to set up .dockerignore with Laravel Sail?

Tags: docker, laravel-sail

After Laravel Sail install, I published the Laravel Sail docker files to my project following the [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#sail-customization). The directory is at `{project root}/docker/8.1`. This directory is also the one specified as build context in the `docker-compose.yml` file. I added a `.dockerignore` file in that directory with the following content:

```
**/.devcontainer
**/.git
**/.vscode
**/docker
[...]
```

When I terminal into the laravel container, the directories and files in my `.dockerignore` have been copied over despite `[internal] load .dockerignore` log statement on `sail build`. `sail build` is basically an alias for `docker compose build`.

How can I set-up my `.dockerignore` for it to be applied on container build?

As a side-note, I don't really understand how the project source files are copied over to the container, as the `Dockerfile` does not seem to contain `COPY` or `ADD` instructions wrt these.

I have looked on this site for answers and on the web without success. I also went through the laravel/sail github issues.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the project files are copied over to the container using a volume. This is why the `.dockerignore` file is ignored. I decided to replace the volume by a `COPY` command in the `Dockerfile`:

```
COPY --chown=$WWWUSER:$WWWGROUP . /var/www/html/
```

I had to change the `docker-compose.yml` `build` directive as follow:

```
 build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./docker/8.1/Dockerfile
    args:
        WWWUSER: "${WWWUSER}"
        WWWGROUP: "${WWWGROUP}"
```

I adjusted relative paths to local files in the `Dockerfile`.

I placed the `.dockerignore` in the project root and it is now taken into account as expected.

Answer (score 0):

replace `dockerfile: ./docker/8.1` with `context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1` in the `docker-compose.yml` file